# How do I scan a thousand double sided pages into a PDF?

Tags: windows, pdf

My scanner (Brother MFC-J825dw) will only scan one side at a time in the sheet feeder. I have a document that is double sided. How can I make a PDF out of it so the pages are in order, automatically? If I scan both sides, I end up with 2 PDFs, one with even pages, and one with odd pages (that might be backwards). I have a PDF editor (PDF Viewer Plus) that can insert/delete/move pages, but that gets ridiculous for so many pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to do a bit of tweaking to make sure its correct but [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) has a built in alternate mix plugin that'll do the trick. You do need to make sure the pages are in order, you have a file for odd and even pages (no skipping blanks - It'll fairly naively interleave them!), and you've loaded the files with the odd and even pages in order. If one of the stacks is scanned in reverse order, there's an option for that (the screenshot, from the [manual](http://www.pdfsam.org/uploads/pdfsam-1.1.0-tutorial.pdf) shows the 2nd document reversed for example)

[image]

Needs java, but is generally pretty fast.